# add new object at the top of uitableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i am new in ios world, i have some data to be loaded in table view controller and thats load perfectly.. now if a new insert were done the new data is added to a NSMutableArray starting from index 0 (new data is at the top and old data are after them) now after updating the NSMutableArray with the new data i call [tableview reloadData].

my aim is to show the new data at the top of table view controller (index 0) but nothing of the new data is loaded ! why ?

this is the code i use to load table cell, where data is the NSMutableArray containing my objects :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", indexPath.row];

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];


        // add description
        UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,25, 260, 50)];
        text.numberOfLines=3;
        text.text= [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] desc];
        text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        text.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
        text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
        [cell addSubview:text];
    }

    //use your cell here
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines =3;

    // cell font
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show how you're adding (or inserting) the new data to your mutable array?

Comment: I test it using debug it added perfectly

Comment: i have an idea.. do you think that becouse the cell is created for the first time and then we reload it with new data it dose not load ! i mean when calling back cellForRowAtIndexPath the cell != nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code your putting in your only assigning the value to the UILabel the first time the cell is created, on any dequeue methods where cell != nil then you just change the font and color for the label already in the cell since your using StyleValue1

```
// add description
    UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,25, 260, 50)];
    text.numberOfLines=3;
    text.text= [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] desc];
    text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    text.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
    text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:text];
```

You do not need this if you just use the label that is associated already with the cell, otherwise if you do need this then you should give the label tag so that you can retrieve it again from the cell when you go to display.

Also your adding the subview to the cell instead of the content view of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
        UILabel *text;
        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", indexPath.row];

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];


    // add description
    text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,25, 260, 50)];
    text.numberOfLines=3;        
    text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    text.tag = 1000;

    text.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
    text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
    [cell addSubview:text];
} else {
    text = (UILabel*)[cell viewForTag:1000];
}

// Here you update the value of text
text.text= [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] desc];

//use your cell here
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines =3;

// cell font
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: yes that is the problem .. when recreating the cell it dose not = nil

Comment: how can i do this ? i tried to repeat the code with if (cel != nill) but then i have cells written over each other

Comment: what to do is in the cell == nil portion give the label a tag text.tag = 1000; then move the setting of the text to the outside i.e. after the if (cell == nil) then if the cell != nil you do cell viewForTag:1000 and that will provide you the already created label with all your defaults, then you can do what else you need too

Comment: but there is a case the run goes into (cell != nil) at the first data load !

Comment: Right so set up everything in that instance should be cell == nil then once it is set up you can use the tag for the next time that cell occurs so you can put the correct information into it.

Comment: i did not get it sorry :( what do you mean !

Comment: Updated the code so it should now help you understand what is meant

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding: A table view cell is normally an object of a certain structure (say, a title and a subtitle) that is identified by an identifier. So, in the simplest case, all cells of a table view have the same structure and thus the same identifier. The reason is that a table view cell can be re-used: If a cell is scrolled out of the screen, it is put back into a pool, and when a  new cell is scrolled into the screen, a cell of the pool is used to display new data. In this case it make no sense at all to create a new identifier for each row of the table.
You problem might be that you ask the table view for a cell with an unknown identifier, which you create dynamically using `NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", indexPath.row];`
I suggest using a single table view cell type, identified by a single identifier, and setting its property `cell.textLabel.text` accordingly.

Comment: i do need the label becouse i have other customization not showing in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following things:

1.Change your code to below , it should work:

move your text UILabel as a iVar in the MyCell and add it there to the cellView. Just configure the information alone based on different index  outside the initialization block.

(It is a good practice to move static style methods to the initialization phase itself. )

```
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];



        cell.text.numberOfLines=3;
        text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        cell.text.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
        cell.text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
       // [cell addSubview:text];
     cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines =3;

    // cell font
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }


 cell.text.text= [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] desc];
    //use your cell here
```

1. Also check if your properly removing the previous items from your mutable array.